# ansible how to load variables from another role, without executing it?

Tags: ansible

I have a task to create a one-off cleanup playbook which is using variables from a role, but i don't need to execute that role. Is there a way to provide a role name to get everything from it's defaults and vars, without hardcoding paths to it? I also want to use vars defined in group_vars or host_vars with higher precedence than the ones included from role.

Example task:

```yaml
- name: stop kafka and zookeeper services if they exist
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: stopped
  with_items:
    - "{{ kafka_service_name }}"
    - "{{ zookeeper_service_name }}"
  ignore_errors: true
```

where `kafka_service_name` and `zookeeper_service_name` are contained in role `kafka`, but may also be present in  i.e. group_vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a fairly hacky solution, which looks like this:

```yaml
- name: save old host_vars
  set_fact:
      old_host_vars: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"

- name: load kafka role variables
  include_vars:
    dir: "{{ item.root }}/{{ item.path }}"
  vars:
    params:
      files:
        - kafka
      paths: "{{ ['roles'] + lookup('config', 'DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH') }}"
  with_filetree: "{{ lookup('first_found', params) }}"
  when: item.state == 'directory' and item.path in ['defaults', 'vars']

- name: stop kafka and zookeeper services if they exist
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: stopped
  with_items:
    - "{{ old_host_vars['kafka_service_name'] | default(kafka_service_name) }}"
    - "{{ old_host_vars['zookeeper_service_name'] | default(zookeeper_service_name) }}"
```

include_vars task  finds the first `kafka` role folder in ./roles and in default role locations, then includes files from directories defaults and vars, in correct order.

I had to save old hostvars due to `include_vars` having higher priority than anything but extra vars as per [ansible doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable), and then using included var only if old_host_vars returned nothing.

If you don't have a requirement to load group_vars - include vars works quite nice in one task and looks way better.

**UPD:** Here is the regexp that i used to replace vars with `old_host_vars` hack.
This was tested in vscode search/replace, but can be adjusted for any other editor

Search for vars that start with kafka_:
`\{\{ (kafka_\w*) \}\}`

Replace with:
`{{ old_host_vars['$1'] | default($1) }}`

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to use the syntax highlighting markup for your yaml block

Comment: @mdaniel, good call, can't get used to the fact that SO is finally using syntax highlighters

Answer (score 0):

I had a different scenario for a similar case you mentioned.
Lets say that the cleanup playbook was part of another long-play, yet you still want the ability to run it stand-alone (one-off as you say)

so my large play ( which is install & cleanup ) was:

```
# file: hostsetup.yml
# play which variables are loaded by the roles
...
---

- name: big task that install & cleanup later
  roles:
   - kafka
   - zookeeper
  
  - name: cleanup
    include_task: playbooks/my_one_off_play.yml
```

Which in the "hostsetup" case we do want to run the role's tasks.

And the one-off script incase i just want to cleanup w/o the long play of "hostsetup" requires just the vars from both roles:

```
# play where variables doesn't exists because there are no roles defined inside
ansible-playbook playbooks/my_one_off_play.yml
```

So i just added to this one-off playbook:

```
# file: playbooks/my_one_off_play.yml 
---
- name: cleanup stuff
  vars_files:
    - roles/kafra/vars/main.yml
    - roles/zookeeper/vars/main.yml
```

And in such case, no matter which play i use ( the large one or one-off ) the vars are loaded anyway by each ...